# initialized listview with extra data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

i develop an android app which contain a listview initialized by loading item from my server.

the data in my server contain three columns id and content and information , i load the content in the listview.

i need when i click item in the list view to load the item information in new activity.

the problem here is in new activity when i try to load the item information i need the item id .

so how i can do this ?

This is the code for initialized the listview

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(qresult);
        for ( int i =0; i<jarray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = json.getString("Qcontent");
            q=json.getString("Qid");// how to send this id to the next activity
            listitems.add(s);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Comment: put the ids in a arraylist and send it to next activity

Comment: nut the problem is how to make an app know that this id for this item ? can you give me a sample code ?!

Comment: i don't understand this id for this item!

Comment: you can use a map for key value pairs.

Comment: i mean that i have more than one item , lets say we have 5 items so we have 5 id's , so how i connect each id with the correct item ?

Comment: can you post your complete code?. you can use hashmap. map.put("key",value); to get map.get("key");

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your intent's extras.

```
intent.putExtra("id", q);
```

Then start the activity.
In the second activity's onCreate(), add

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String q =  extras.getString("id"); //this is your id
```

Also, you may consider moving `notifyDataSetChanged()` to outside the for loop.